# Error "functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE", not time stamp

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I'm trying to create the following index;

```
CREATE INDEX idx_concat_paostartno_paostartsuff ON 
    dmv_os_addbase_residential (concat(pao_start_number || pao_start_suffix));
```

I get the error;

> ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

I think this is the mixing of types, as `pao_start_number` is type `bigint` and `pao_start_suffix` is `varchar`.  I've tried to resolve as;

```
CREATE INDEX idx_concat_paostartno_paostartsuff ON  
  dmv_os_addbase_residential (concat((pao_start_number :: text) || pao_start_suffix))
```

but same error.

Am I right in identifying that cause of the error and how can I resolve it?
I am using Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want

```
CREATE INDEX idx_concat_paostartno_paostartsuff
   ON dmv_os_addbase_residential ((pao_start_number || pao_start_suffix));
```

This index can only be used for queries like

```
SELECT *
FROM dmv_os_addbase_residential
WHERE pao_start_number || pao_start_suffix <operator> <constant>;
```

where `<operator>` is one of `=`, `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=`.

Comment: I did, thank you. I see the 'CONCAT' was part my problem, why is that?

Comment: The operator `||` is `IMMUTABLE`, while the function `concat` is `STABLE`. The reason is that `concat` can operate on `any` argument type, casting the arguments to `text`, and not all type casts to `text` are `IMMUTABLE` (e.g., casting from `timestamp with time zone` to `text` depends on the `TimeZone` parameter).

Comment: I tried the same using ```||``` but it did not help in my case.
```CREATE INDEX courses_search_idx ON courses USING GIN (to_tsvector(courses.title || courses.description));
```

Comment: @AnishJain That's an unrelated problem: the `to_tsvector` function in its one-argument form is *not* immutable, because it depends on the value of the parameter `default_text_search_config`. Use the two-argument form that specifies the language.

Answer (score 4):

Timezone aware timestamps are considered mutable by Postgres. So that is why it is failing. I found the following GIST which solved the problem for me:
https://gist.github.com/cobusc/5875282

shortcut to GIST contents (thank you cobusc):

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name_idx ON my_table (date(created_ts at TIME ZONE 'UTC'));
```

worked for me